# Combining Secrets With NPM Build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, next.js

NEXTJS requires env variables for build but not after. Originally using ARG but this seems more secure (ephemeral). However struggling with the documentation on multiple secrets and getting those secrets into a .env file. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID \
  cat /run/secrets/NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID >> .env.local \
  --mount=type=secret,id=NEXT_PUBLIC_IDENTITY_API_KEY \
  cat /run/secrets/NEXT_PUBLIC_IDENTITY_API_KEY >> .env.local \
  --mount=type=secret,id=PRIVATE_KEY \
  cat /run/secrets/PRIVATE_KEY >> .env.local \
  --mount=type=secret,id=CLIENT_EMAIL \
  cat /run/secrets/CLIENT_EMAIL >> .env.local \
  --mount=type=secret,id=FIREBASE_TOKEN \
  cat /run/secrets/FIREBASE_TOKEN >> .env.local \
  && npm run build
```

Error Message

```
Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cat /run/secrets/NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID >> .env.local   --mount=type=secret,id=NEXT_PUBLIC_IDENTITY_API_KEY   cat /run/secrets/NEXT_PUBLIC_IDENTITY_API_KEY >> .env.local   --mount=type=secret,id=PRIVATE_KEY   cat /run/secrets/PRIVATE_KEY >> .env.local   --mount=type=secret,id=CLIENT_EMAIL   cat /run/secrets/CLIENT_EMAIL >> .env.local   --mount=type=secret,id=FIREBASE_TOKEN   cat /run/secrets/FIREBASE_TOKEN >> .env.local   && npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

Comment: How can you tell what you're doing here is wrong? Is there an error message? Are the results wrong somehow? Kindly edit your post to include this information.

Comment: my apologies, done. its now in the post

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling this is how i got it working

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID \
  --mount=type=secret,id=NEXT_PUBLIC_IDENTITY_API_KEY \
  --mount=type=secret,id=APRIVATE_KEY \
  --mount=type=secret,id=CLIENT_EMAIL \
  cat /run/secrets/NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID > .env.local && \
  echo "" >> .env.local && cat /run/secrets/NEXT_PUBLIC_IDENTITY_API_KEY >> .env.local && \
  echo "" >> .env.local && cat /run/secrets/CLIENT_EMAIL >> .env.local && \
  echo "" >> .env.local && cat /run/secrets/APRIVATE_KEY >> .env.local && \
  npm run build && \
  rm .env.local
```